# How can I use Azure Active Directory as an identity provider for my webforms and mvc applications?

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-active-directory, asp.net-identity

I have a WebForms application that uses old Membership identity for authentication/authorization. Now I am adding an MVC Core application that needs to share the same users. But .Net Core doesn't support old way of authentication.

So I am thinking about migrating to a 3rd party provider. We already use Azure. But I cannot find a simple tutorial on how to do this migration to Azure Active Directory.

Comment: Take a look at this code sample to get started with a single tenant web app.. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/1-WebApp-OIDC/1-1-MyOrg .. In case you're looking for multi-tenant look at `1-2-AnyOrg` and in case you need ability for Personal Accounts (like abc@outlook.com) to login as well.. `1-3-AnyOrgorPersonal` under this tree.. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/1-WebApp-OIDC

Comment: @Rohit Saigal Thank you for your comment! Here is what confuses me. I read, "Select Register to create the application." What if I already have an application? I have a set of old-style role-based tables that hold my users and roles. I need to convert it to new identity. Also, the example is about MVC Core, which is good, but I also have a WebForms application. Will it do? And how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an [article](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopModernizing/wiki/09.-How-to-add-authentication-authorization-with-Azure-Active-Directory) about using Azure Active Directory as an identity provider for the webforms and mvc applications.

Also, you can refer to the [official samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code).

> Select Register to create the application." What if I already have an
>   application?

If the application you mentioned refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app. You can use the old one(need to change the settings) or just create a new one.